# How can I encode in a format that's not supported by Media Recorder?

Tags: java, android, audio, wav, pcm

I am writing an android app that will be a voice recorder app that needs to record a .wav file at a specific setting. It needs to match the following information:

```
   File Type: Windows PCM
   File extension: .wav
   22050 Hz, 16-bit, Stereo
```

The file information above is from [this file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h9Op9OvCCaDPjCre7BfiY1py2srHkJeR/view?usp=sharing). It is a standard Windows file that our server will play. If the file doesn't match these settings, our server will not interpret the file. I have tried recording like this but it will not work:

```
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPreference", MODE_PRIVATE);
        int curValue = prefs.getInt("recordCount", 0); // Getting current value of sharedPref
        String fileNameWNum = "Recording" + curValue + ".wav";
        ...
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(22050);
```

This method is making a .wav file but not encoding it. Can anyone suggest how I can encode the infomation?

EDIT: [This is the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1398J51XFBU7sWt0XS2j-rrSvwGSDNuE6/view?usp=drivesdk) being recorded by my software

Comment: Can You share the file that is recorded by your code. Check the parameters of this file.

Comment: @mail2subhajit I have edited the question to include this file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the file (Recording 8.wav) that you have shared.

Property of the file.

Duration: 00:00:38.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15 kb/s
   Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: **amr_wb** (sawb / 0x62776173), **16000 Hz, mono**, flt, 13
kb/s (default)

Please check this reference code for [Wav recording on Android](https://code.google.com/archive/p/simplesound/source/default/source) and [Audio Record Class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html)

Note : Normal MediaRecorder don't support wav recording in Android.

Comment: what library could I replace MediaRecorder with that would?

Comment: also which file is this? Recording 8.wav or Ring 05.wav

Comment: Please go through the AudioRecord Class and example for it.